# Tomcat server8 failed to start at local host, how to solve this

Tags: java, tomcat8

copy of stack Trace

```
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.28.0
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.2
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_10-b18
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         F:\Aakash\JAVA\Java Programs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=F:\Aakash\JAVA\Java Programs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=F:\Aakash\JAVA\Java Programs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\endorsed
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;C:\eclipse-jee-mars-M1-win32\eclipse;;.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 688 ms
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [XMLSchema.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [datatypes.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [xml.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [j2ee_web_services_1_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [j2ee_web_services_client_1_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-app_2_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [j2ee_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-app_2_5.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_5.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-app_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-fragment_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-common_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_6.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-app_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-fragment_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [web-common_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_7.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [jsp_2_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory locationFor
WARNING: The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5080)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Oct 31, 2015 6:55:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: This is a clean (out of the box) Tomcat? Which Java version are you using?

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader` imho sth. messed with your classpath. Could you post the BOM of the app you are trying to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this one. I'm using tomcat version 8 and JDK 7. I think the mistake is I added servlet-api jar, because of the I getting class not found(it takes wrong class), and then null pointer exception. So I delete that jar from ext folder. Its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a clean Tomcat install. It looks like the servlet API JAR is missing. Do a clean install of Tomcat, preferrably downloaded from https://tomcat.apache.org

If you still see the error and you are using a 3rd party Tomcat package, report a bug to the package maintainers.